# Node.js ES6 how to export class from module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I'm trying to export an ES6 class from a CommonJS module in Node.js 6.2.0

```
class MyClass{
    //class contents here
}

exports = MyClass;
```

Then import it in another module:

```
var MyClass = require('/path/to/module.js')
var instance = new MyClass();
```

However I'm getting the following exception:

```
TypeError: MyClass is not a constructor
```

How can I properly do it?

Please note that I'm not using Babel/Tranceur it's pure JS as implemented in the latest Node 6.2.0 which according to Kangax implements ES6 in 93%.

//Edit: this is not a problem with exports vs module.exports. While using exports alone I'm getting some object with `__proto__` set.

Comment: Try logging what you get after requiring the module. _If it isn't a constructor, what is it?_

Comment: *"this is not a problem with exports vs module.exports"* Yes it is! `exports = MyClass;` doesn't export anything. It's a noop. `module.exports = ...;` is the way to export a single value from a module. The duplicate explains why `exports = ...;` doesn't work.

Comment: You should mark @Bergi  answer as correct (by click on gray 'ceck' button on left side of his answer)

Answer (score 37):

You will need to assign to `module.exports`, not the local `exports` variable.

Comment: @kubal5003: From that very article: "*`require` returns an object, which references the value of `module.exports` for a given file*". How is my answer wrong? Have you tried using `module.exports = MyClass`?

Comment: @kubal5003: This answer is correct. If you don't believe that then you need to spend more time learning about Node/CommonJS modules.

Comment: This worked for me. This should be accepted as solution.